# Java Error (Runtime Exception - Illegal Argument Exception) - Android

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

Here's the error message I'm getting: `E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. I took out the app file name/package name, but everything else is there. The app is designed to target the Gingerbread, but has a minimum SDK level for the Froyo. I'm basically get an AVR message when I try and launch the app on the AVD. The source code is ~460 lines long, so I'm not sure where the error is (there are no syntax errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong). Here's the pastebin URL for the source code that I've put up: http://pastebin.com/EtUP2CAB. I've seen some stuff about DecimalFormatSymbols and the SensorSimulator, etc., but I'm still confused. Hence, I'd appreciate some help with locating the issue here causing this error.

EDIT: Here's the error log for the last run I did:

```
02-03 20:51:21.724: D/AndroidRuntime(468): Shutting down VM
02-03 20:51:21.724: W/dalvikvm(468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deitel.flagquizgame/com.deitel.flagquizgame.FlagQuizGame}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:186)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.deitel.flagquizgame.FlagQuizGame.resetQuiz(FlagQuizGame.java:136)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.deitel.flagquizgame.FlagQuizGame.onCreate(FlagQuizGame.java:92)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-03 20:51:21.784: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  ... 11 more
02-03 20:51:27.464: I/Process(468): Sending signal. PID: 468 SIG: 9
```

Comment: pls add the error log alos..line number at which you are getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

seems in line

```
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfFlags);
```

numberOfFlags are not positive number, its 0 or less than 0, check numberOfFlags value by debugging.